# Modifying value in vector inside of a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, reference

I have a function

```
void build_path(map<State, vector<State> >& path) {
    State some_state(1, 2, 3);
    path[some_key_value].add(some_state);
}
```

Would the vector at `some_key_value` in `path` be modified? I know that path will be modified since I passed it in as a reference but I'm not sure about the vector.

Comment: Assuming `path[some_key_value]` is the vector you're referring to then yes it will be modified.

Comment: @StevenZhao FYI, you could have simply tried this and seen the result for yourself faster than it took to post a question here and get a reply.

Comment: `add` ? I don't think a vector has `add`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can modify the vector at `some_key_value` in the `path` map, but
there is no `add` function for vector.
You can either use:
- [`push_back`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/) to add element at the end of the vector, after its current last element
- [`insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/insert/) to insert new element before the element at the specified position

You can also use [`at`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/at/), if you want to change the existing value at a certain position.